# django url collision

Tags: django, collision, url-pattern

I have django app, and have one problem:
Category and page application have the same url:

Here is category.urls.py:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url('(?P<slug>[0-9A-Za-z-_.]+)/$', Category.as_view(), name='category')
)
```

And here is page.urls.py:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
   url(r'^(?P<slug>[0-9A-Za-z-_.]+)$', Page.as_view(), name='page')
)
```

So here is a problem - you can't open page with such urls, so i need this solution:

If here is exists Category with slug from url - open Category view, if there is no Category with such url, go to Page view.

But i don't know how to do this with RIGHT on django, without creating additional function like this:

```
def freeurl(request, slug):
   try:
      Category.objects.get(slug=slug)
      go to Category view
   except Category.DoesNotExists:
       go to Page view
```

is it possible ?

Comment: ask your SEO department what should happen when there will be category with the same slug as some page has .)

Comment: Well, they don't care :)

Comment: well, if functionality is subordinated to something like SEO, that sucks .)

Comment: That it, clients worrying about making money, about SEO and some other "good" words, but the don't care is it possible or not :)

Answer (score 0):

it's simple: include both `urls.py` with different prefix .)

main `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... snip ...
    (r'^category/', include('category.urls')),
    (r'^page/', include('page.urls')),
)
```

EDIT:

your proposition could look like this then:

```
def freeurl(request, slug):
    try:
        cat = Category.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except Category.DoesNotExist:
        try:
            page = Page.objects.get(slug=slug)
        except Page.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404()
        else:
            return render_to_response('page.html', {'object': page}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return render_to_response('cat.html', {'object': cat}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**EDIT 2:**

there's a project solving exactly your issue, check it out:

https://github.com/jacobian/django-multiurl

Comment: Thank you, i know. But i can't using prefix for both category and page  view. That's why i ask this question....

Comment: so prefix it in directly in pattern isn't possible as well, I guess? Ie. `r'^category-(?P<slug>[0-9A-Za-z-_.]+)$'` for categories and `r'^page-(?P<slug>[0-9A-Za-z-_.]+)$'` for pages

Comment: no, this is not acceptable solutions too.
i thought django have build  in solution like i posted in my question

Comment: i also edited my post w/ something you would consider acceptable

Answer (score 0):

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(
        r'^category/(?P<slug>[0-9A-Za-z-_.]+)/$', 
        Category.as_view(), 
        name='category'
    )
)

urlpatterns += patterns('',
   url(
       r'^page/(?P<slug>[0-9A-Za-z-_.]+)/$', 
       Page.as_view(), 
       name='page'
   )
)
```

Comment: no, i can't add category/ and page/ word in URL. This is requirements from SEO department.